# React Native bundle in release APK is not working

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm newbie in RN. I have a problem with building release APK. I'm doing following steps:

1. rm -rf node_modules & npm install
2. Generating bundle:

react-native bundle

```
 --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

3. cd android & ./gradlew assembleRelease

app/build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInDebug: true,
    bundleInRelease: true,
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

....
```

It seems bundleInRelease option is not working properly. However ./gradlew assembleDebug works perfect! Please help!

Comment: You just have to use assembleRelease. Bundling will happen itself.

Comment: I have tried to use assembleRelease. But some functionality doesn't work and when I launch npm install on terminal it works well. However, when I'm building apk with assembleDebug everything works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Some functionality doesn't work"? Are you proguarding your app?

Comment: I used 'react-native-bitcoinjs-lib' library, as well as, I know there is no proguard rules. When I launch debug APK everything works fine, but on release APK I got following error: "Expected property '0' of type ECPair, got k"

Comment: I noted that, when I set bundleInDebug: false I got similar error in debug apk.

Comment: @BakhromAchilov : have you set up signing for your app? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! 
I used 'react-native-bitcoinjs-lib' library and the thing is the library was not fully configured. By documentation, for generating release APK, additionally, I had to create file in project named metro.config.js. And wrote following code in it:

```
module.exports = {
    transformer: {
      minifierConfig: {
        mangle: {
          keep_fnames: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, everything works fine.